# why does iterator not enforce hasnext call?

Tags: java, iterator

It seems like quite a good method if hasNext and Next worked  like this:

```
boolean hasNextCalled = false;

boolean hasNext() {
  hasNextCalled  = true
}

next() {
  assert hasNextCalled
}
```

This way we would never land up in  a case where we would get NoSuchElementException().
Any practical reason why hasNext() call is not enforced ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` is a runtime exception, and reflects programmer error...exactly like your approach does.  It's not obligatory to call `hasNext()` because maybe you don't need to -- you know the size of the collection in advance, for example, and know how many calls to `next()` you can make.

The point is that you're exchanging one way of reporting programmer error for...another way of reporting programmer error that can disable some useful approaches.

Answer (score 9):

What would be the benefit? You're simply replacing a `NoSuchElementException` with an `AssertionError`, plus introducing a tiny bit of overhead. Also, since `Iterator` is an interface, you couldn't implement this once; it would have to go in every implementation of `Iterator`. Plus the documentation doesn't impose a requirement to call `hasNext` before calling `next`, so your proposal would break the current contract. Such a change would break any code that was written to rely on a `NoSuchElementException`. Finally, assertions can be turned off in production code, so you would still need the `NoSuchElementException` mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we already know that there are elements left. For example, maybe we're iterating over two equally-sized lists in lockstep, and we only need to call `hasNext` on one iterator to check for both. Also, `assert`ing the `hasNext` call doesn't actually prevent anyone from calling `next` without `hasNext`, especially if assertions are off.

Answer (score 1):

You may know there's a `next()`, for example if you always have pairs of elements, one call to `hasNext()` will allow two calls to `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents. Here the API makes an **assumption** about the client usage and forces that. Let us say I am always sure that I get back only 1 result then it is better to by pass the `hasNext()` call and directly retrieve the element by calling just `next()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the assert you suggest would only run when assertions are enabled.

But the main issue is that you consider only one use-case. The library is designed to support programmers in their work with minimal restrictions, and each class and method has to fit into a cohesive and coherent whole.

Other posters give good reasons also (as I was typing), especially that Iterator is an Interface, and has many implementations.